# Link multiple Google webmaster tools accounts to single Analytics property

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-search-console

I tried to look for a good solution but couldn't find any.

I try to link multiple Google webmaster tools accounts to a single Analytics property.

- I tried creating multiple views, but it seems you can't link it to a view.
- I found a solution to add multiple domains to a Google Analytics property, but this seems outdated since Universal tracking

Note: probably some people might say I should 301 redirect the domains for duplicate content. But they are regionaly implemented using the hreflang alternate method which should be just fine.

Comment: No, I finally setup rel=canonical tags to one extension and try to keep my traffic on one extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can link multiple Google Analytics accounts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

// Second tracker 
_gaq.push(['secondTracker._setAccount','UA-YYYYYYYY-Y']); 
_gaq.push(['secondTracker._trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +   '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

See: http://seo-website-designer.com/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Multiple-Accounts

Comment: I know this, and in Analytics I already see data for both domains. Only I want to add two "Webmaster Tools" accounts to my Analytics property for more insight in Search terms / queries